# How to generate client certificate using https://test.mosquitto.org/ssl/index.php in esp32 sdk example ssl_mutual_auth?

Tags: ssl, mqtt

I'm rather new to .php scripts so i can hardly understand it. And im having difficulties generating a certificate using https://test.mosquitto.org/ssl/index.php this link because all i get is a index.php file.

I have already installed the apache-v2 utility and used wget command followed by this link to get the localserver .
Now when i enter https://localhost/index.php i get everything except the key generator function . And everytime i paste csr value into the dialog box the page gets refreshed .

Comment: That page is currently broken, it should not download the php file, it should run it and show you page about how to create the certificate.

Comment: Hi hardilib,
Thanks for the response. Are you familiar with another method you can point me to establish secure communication with a broker.

Comment: There is no other way to get a certificate signed by the CA the test.mosquitto.org broker will accept as a client certificate. The site is working fine for me, make sure you clear the cache.

Comment: Yes the site worked fine after clearing the cache,thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not your fault, just a server error. It should be working again now.

Comment: Hi ralight,
Thanks for the response. It is still not working.

Comment: Just saying "it's not working" isn't very useful, please describe what is not working.

Comment: I was responding to the previous statement which was abbreviating 'it' as in server.